# Decoupling Meteor Client and Server using mondora/asteroid - but how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I'm currently figuring out how to use Meteor with my own Angular project-structure & templates. There is a library called Asteroid ("A javascript client (browser and node) for a Meteor backend, Asteroid gives the possibility to connect to a Meteor backend with any JS app.") at

https://github.com/mondora/asteroid

It is documented okay, but the thing I miss, is how I organize my files and create a project structure. I set up my client, integrating the asteroid files using require, it works, but when it comes to creating the Asteroid instance using the Meteor server as the host, I don't know how to create the server, e.g. the "host" param and run it on my local machine.

```
var a = new Asteroid(host, ssl, interceptor)
```

Has anyone used Asteroid before and can point me in the right direction? It would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem integrating meteor backend with Polymer frontend. We used [meteor-build-client](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client) tool to decouple the client and server parts of our meteor application. It will give you a .js file containing all the client-side code. You need to include this file on your front-end application.

Our meteor project have most its files on the server and packages folder, and just a call to the main Polymer element on the client folder to start-up the frontend application. Remember that any client-side code present in meteor application will be run automatically when you call the client-side script.

In order to connect to the server, you need to provide meteor runtime config using something like this:

```
    var ip= window.location.hostname.toString();
var port = 3000;
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {
    "meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.1.0.2",
    "ROOT_URL":"http://"+ip+":"+port,
    "ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"",
    "DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL":"http://"+ip+":"+port
};
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!